# How to install peerjs server on windows server with multiple IP addresses

Tags: windows, server, ip-address, peerjs

I have installed the peerjs server on my windows server as per github, and successfully get the message:

> “Started PeerServer on ::, port: 9000, path: /myapp”.

I then opened port 9000 in the windows firewall, and find the following two entries in the netstat listing:-

> TCP    0.0.0.0:9000           vmBCE3892:0            LISTENING
> [node.exe]

> TCP    [::]:9000              vmBCE3892:0            LISTENING
> [node.exe]

My server has 2 different IP addresses for 2 different web applications under IIS.

To check peerjs connectivity I used telnet as follows:-

> telnet ipaddress 9000

with each IP address, neither would connect.

I cannot see how to tie the peerjs server to one of the ipaddresses or the corresponding domain name.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my ISP blocks all ports other than 80 & 443, despite them appearing  to be available in my firewall. As for the two IP adresses, either would have reached  peerjs server had the port been open.